# Can I make this code shorter somehow? Is it possible to use lambda here?

Tags: c#, lambda

I must calculate how many players were in the hall and return their IDs.

I was wondering if it's possible to make this code shorter.

```cs
int[] Counter = new int[100]; //The Size of the array was given by of the task

for (int i = 0; i < Person.Count; i++)
{
    if (Person[i].In_Out == "in")
    {
        Counter[Person[i].ID - 1]++;
    }

    else if (Person[i].In_Out == "out")
    {
        Counter[Person[i].ID - 1]--;
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    if (Counter[i] > 0)
    {
        Console.Write(" {0} ",i+1);
    }

}
```

Comment: You are assuming the IDs go from 1 to 100...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, let's compress the existing code (if you use `Count` somehow):

```
int[] Counter = new int[100];

foreach (var person in Person)
  Counter[person.Id - 1] += 
      person.In_Out == "in" ? 1 
    : person.In_Out == "out" ? -1 
    : 0;

for (int i = 0; i < Counter.Length; ++i)
  if (Counter[i] > 0)
    Console.Write($" {i + 1} "); // <- note that i is index, not Id
```

If you want to *query* the `Person` collection, try *Linq*:

```
using System.Linq;

...

Console.Write(string.Join(" ", Person // join in a single string
  .Where(p => p.In_Out == "in")       // all persons which are in
  .Select(p => p.Id)));               // while printing their Ids
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your ultimate requirement is to display `ID` values where the value of `In_Out` is equal to `"in"` - this would be an alternative to the approach used with the `Counter` array.

---

The `System.Linq` namespace includes a `.Where` clause which can filter the `Person` list based on the `In_out` field using a predicate `p => p.In_Out == "in"`

`System.Linq` also contains the `Select` clause which can pick up the `ID` from each item, resulting in an IEnumerable just for those IDs.

Lastly, `string.Join` can be used with an `IEnumerable` to join the ID values together into a single string before displaying them.

```
var ids = Person
    .Where(p => p.In_Out == "in")
    .Select(p => p.ID);

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", ids));
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to shorten your code with lambda expression without modifying too much.

You could use following to shorten your code:

```
...

foreach(Person p in Person){

...

}
```

Introduce **ternary operator** will also help you dramatically to short your conditional assignments as presented by @Dmitry Bychenko.

Comment: If I were you, I'd delete this answer before you start getting downvotes...

Comment: Thank You everyone

Comment: Why would i do such a thing? @insane_developer 
I thought this website was made for asking questions :D
I have huge exams coming up. I will get extra points if i use as few code lines as possible.

Comment: You're here right my dear, everything right so far. Good luck by learning and your future improvements.